# Error Stops R Code Despite tryCatch. How Can I Keep It Running?

Tags: r, csv, error-handling, try-catch

I'm looking to loop through multiple cases that have .csv files associated with each case. However, some of these files are missing, and as R tries to open them, throws an error. I've tried to fix this by using `tryCatch` so the variable associated with the file will just be set to `NA` and the code can continue. It works in that the variable is set to `NA`, but the error still stops the code. Is there a way to keep the code going? The snippet of my code is below.

```
for (j in 1:length(cases)){
  filename12 <- paste0('snow_prob_verif_', cases[j], '12.csv')
  filename24 <- paste0('snow_prob_verif_', cases[j], '24.csv')
  filename36 <- paste0('snow_prob_verif_', cases[j], '36.csv')
  filename48 <- paste0('snow_prob_verif_', cases[j], '48.csv')
  filename60 <- paste0('snow_prob_verif_', cases[j], '60.csv')

  tryCatch(expr={
  verifdata12 <- read.csv(filename12, header = TRUE)
  verifdata12$start <- strtrim(verifdata12$start, 8)
  verifdata12$start <- as.Date(verifdata12$start, "%Y%m%d")},
  error = function(){verifdata12 <- NA})
  tryCatch(expr={
  verifdata24 <- read.csv(filename24, header = TRUE)
  verifdata24$start <- strtrim(verifdata24$start, 8)
  verifdata24$start <- as.Date(verifdata24$start, "%Y%m%d")},
  error = function(){verifdata24 <- NA})
  tryCatch(expr={
  verifdata36 <- read.csv(filename36, header = TRUE)
  verifdata36$start <- strtrim(verifdata36$start, 8)
  verifdata36$start <- as.Date(verifdata36$start, "%Y%m%d")},
  error = function(){verifdata36 <- NA})
  tryCatch(expr={
  verifdata48 <- read.csv(filename48, header = TRUE)
  verifdata48$start <- strtrim(verifdata48$start, 8)
  verifdata48$start <- as.Date(verifdata48$start, "%Y%m%d")},
  error = function(){verifdata48 <- NA})
  tryCatch(expr={
  verifdata60 <- read.csv(filename60, header = TRUE)
  verifdata60$start <- strtrim(verifdata60$start, 8)
  verifdata60$start <- as.Date(verifdata60$start, "%Y%m%d")},
  error = function(){verifdata60 <- NA})
```

Thank you!

Comment: if the issue is just that the files are missing consider using file.exists() to test and avoid tryCatch altogether

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!